How do I describe food in solid and liquid forms?
We were at a restaurant. According to the picture on the menu, the dish we ordered had solid strawberries (strawberry pieces) in it. But in the actual dish, there’s no solid strawberries. The “strawberry” in the dish was like jam (dense liquid form). How do I say those 2 forms? Can I call the one from the menu “solid strawberries”, “whole pieces” or “strawberry pieces”? Can I call the strawberry jam “liquid” or say that “is in liquid form”? Are those idiomatic? Thank you.

This question is similar to: What is the word for the edible part of a fruit with rind (e.g., lemon, orange, avocado, watermelon)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Is this question specifically about fruit (which is what the body of the question is about) or about food in general (as indicated by the title)?

@jsw29, it's about both.

It would help to have an example sentence, or at least an indication of whether you want adjective, noun, noun phrase, or something else.

@Stuart F, I already have some phrases in my question as examples. I asked if they're right or idiomatic. But I don't want to limit you to those. People can provide their own ways of expressing those meanings.

I was expecting the dish to contain fresh fruit.
I expected whole pieces of strawberries on the cheesecake instead all we got was:
marinated/macerated strawberry, preserve, thick strawberry sauce, coulis, glaze  etc.
The correct terminology depends on the name of the dessert that was served in the restaurant.
strawberry compote

Source
UPDATE  (30/11/24)
Words for describing soft, cooked food such as fruit and vegetables
mushy meaning soft and pulpy

Vegetables and fruit that are mushy are soft and have lost most of their shape.
…simmer gently for 8-10 min or until the tomatoes are very soft and mushy.

gooey meaning soft and sticky

These cakes are fudgy, gooey, and delicious

The OP asks “Can I call the strawberry jam “liquid” or say that “is in liquid form”?
The short answer is no. Jams, preserves, confiture or jelly—its US counterpart—are thick, sweet sticky substances that are not normally drunk in a glass nor poured out of a jar. Commonly, you use a knife to spread it on cakes, bread, scones etc.  while glazes, coulis and reduced sauces are runnier.
Due to its soft, sticky, and viscous texture it would be better to describe strawberry jam as being semi-solid than liquid-like.

I have an impression (although that was not entirely explicit in the question) that the OP is seeking a hypernym for jam, coulis, sauce, etc., as the OP needs to contrast all these things, on one side, with solid pieces of fruit on the other. I take it that your answer is meant to imply that there is no such general term.

@jsw29 is there something wrong with "thick strawberry sauce" as a generic term? If you know what the topping resembled, you can choose between the others. No? If we're talking about vegetables, a thick pureed soup would work, or maybe blitzed and turned into a dip, or mashed (potatoes), creamed, mushy, or simply overcooked. If the OP wants me to include any of the other suggestions they can message me.

Yes, the compote versus the actual fresh fruit. RIGHT.

Can you have "whole pieces" of anything?

In culinary terms, a dish might include strawberries (whole or in pieces), or a strawberry coulis (strawberries cooked down into a liquid).

